# How to unescape Jsoup document?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have html file which contains below content:

```
<html>
    <title><s:message code="test" /></title>
</html>
```

Java Program:

```
String input = readFileAsString(filePath);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);

Elements messageEls = doc.select("s|message");
```

I see output as below:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>&lt;s:message code="test" /&gt;</title> 
 </head>
 <body> 
 </body>
```

Somehow character `<` is converted `&lt`. How can I get original contect without enscape ? Actually I need find elements `<s:message`
 but because of escaping , it's not finding element `<s:message code="test" />` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup escapes because `<s:message />` not a standard HTML tag.

Try to use [XML parser](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser--):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

> Create a new XML parser. This parser assumes no knowledge of the
>   incoming tags and does not treat it as HTML, rather creates a simple
>   tree directly from the input.

Comment: what will be baseUri ?

Comment: See my edited answer. baseUri is the url where HTML comes from, used to fetch relative link. In your case, you don't need that

Comment: I did not get when you said `Jsoup escapes because it's not a standard HTML tag`  because in some of the files it escapes character `<`  but in some other files it does not ?

Comment: `<s:message />` is not a standard html tag, hence jsoup will escape it

Comment: But same code does not escape the `<s:message />`  in other file.  so ,in some file it escapes and in some file it does not. not sure why its like that ?